# Continuous function converge to continuous function in $L^\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let space $C_c(X)$ be space of continuous function with compact support(equipped with sup norm),and $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with esssup norm.

Assume a sequence of continuous function $f_n\in C_c(X)$ that converge in $L^\infty$ to some function $f$

Now is the question is,can we guarantee the function $f$ is always continuous on $\Omega$?

We know $f_n$ must converge to some continuous function(one of representation element in $L^\infty$ is continuous) on $\Omega$.Can we gurantee all the limit of $f_n$ is continuous?

Then why can we use this statement to argue that continuous function with compact support is not dense in $L^\infty$?By the fact that many discontinuous finctions in $L^\infty$?

Comment: When $f_n, f_m$ are continuous, $\|f_n - f_m\|_{\infty}$ is just the usual sup norm.

Comment: @Arctic Cha I know this type of arguement,the point is under the sup norm it converge to continuous function,but that function in $L^\infty$ is equivalent class that agree a.e. so in this equivalent class may have discontinuous function in fact

Comment: The point is that (for $\Omega \neq \varnothing$) there are (lots of) classes in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ that don't have any continuous representative.

Comment: Function $f(x) = 1$ on rational and $0$ for irrational seems to be one of it

Comment: No, that one has $f(x) = 0$ as representative. Think of $f(x) =1$ on $x>0$ and $0$ on $x\le 0$.

Comment: thank you,I got it